# Orientation is only in landscape mode in cameraoverlay view

Tags: iphone, ipad, camera

i Want to open Cameraoverlay view in landscape mode only ...But this code gives me    BAD_Excess..

```
{      
self.imagePickerController = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init ] autorelease];
imagePickerController.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

//Set Notifications so that when user rotates phone, the orientation is reset to landscape.
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

//Refer to the method didRotate:   
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                                             name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];

//Set the picker source as the camera   
self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

//Bring in the picker view   
[self presentModalViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES];
}
```

please solve this issue...
thanks In Advance

Comment: Where is the bad access happening

Comment: [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight]; in didRotate: method i have used this code

Comment: Hi Tejas, If you find any solution for this then plz share this I have same problem to deal with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

go to product>edit schems> enable zombie

this will give you more description about your exception.

Comment: perhaps you didn't change the tab. chose diagnostic tab from above there is a checkbox